# does not accept text values in database query, but allows numbers only

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have a search form to get some information from database by some custom values.
For exampe, my form contain a search keyword, and category id, and price

- `search keyword` : text
- `category id` : int
- `price` : int

Now, when make a query to get some data from database doesn't allow the values that contain characters like `search keyword`, but allows the numbers only like `category id`, `price`.

**Template page HTML**

```
<form action="<?= base_url() ?>classifieds/search/result/" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="search_keyword" id="search_keyword"  />
            <span id="price_fromto">
                <input type="text" name="price_from" id="price_from"  />
                <input type="text" name="price_to" id="price_to" />
            </span>
            <select name="currency" id="currency">
                <option value="">currency</option>
                        <option value=""></option>
            </select>
            <select name="service" id="service">
                <option value="">Offer type</option>
                <option value="wanted"></option>
                <option value="sale">for sale</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="sbmtSearch" id="sbmtSearch" value="search" />
        </form>
```

**Controller code**

```
$this - > load - > model('classifieds'); // load model
$q_s = array(
    'name' = > $this -> input -> get('search_keyword', true),
    'category_id' = > $this -> input -> get('search_category', true),
    'type' = > $this - > input -> get('type', true),
    'price >' = > $this -> input -> get('price_from', true),
    'price <' = > $this -> input -> get('price_to', true), );

// configartion
$output['query'] = $this->classifieds->get_serach_classifieds($q_s); // get content in this model
}
$data['content'] = $this -> load -> view('category', $output, true); // append model content in content variable
$data['title'] = 'search result'; // model model name the page title
$this -> load -> view('index', $data); // load master page ( Container )
```

**Classifieds model**

```
function get_serach_classifieds($q_s) {
        $this->db->where('state', 1);

        foreach ($q_s as $key => $val) {
            if ($val != "" && $val != 0) {
                $this->db->where($key, $val);
            }
        }

        return $this->db->get('content');
    }
```

**The query that created (wrong)**

```
SELECT * FROM (`content`) WHERE `state` = 1 AND `category_id` = '4' AND `price` > '100' AND `price` < '800' LIMIT 15
```

**Supposed the query to be this way (correct)**

```
SELECT * FROM (`content`) WHERE `state` = 1 AND 'name' = 'bmw' AND 'type' = 'wanted' AND `category_id` = '4' AND `price` > '100' AND `price` < '800' LIMIT 15
```

What is the problem in my code which makes the query does not accept text values ?

Comment: Are you getting data via get ? Can you check `var_dump($q_s)` in your get_serach_classifieds function.

Comment: Yes, everything is alright, I've tested everything. the problem when getting the data from database .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$val != 0` seems to be the problem.  It's not true when compare to a a string.

Something like this should work:

```
foreach ($q_s as $key => $val) {
        if ((is_string($val) && $val != "") || (is_int($val) && $val !=0)) {
            $this->db->where($key, $val);
        } 
    }
```